# Map one type to another type

Tags: typescript

This is a problem I come across quite frequently. What's the best way of converting one type to another? A possible use case would be extending an object that comes from the server with UI specific properties.

```
interface RawData {
  id: number
  someOtherData: string
}

interface ViewData extends RawData {
  isVisible: boolean
}

const rawData: RawData = getDataFromServer() // Returns data with type RawData
const viewData: ViewData = mapRawDataToViewData(rawData)

function mapRawDataToViewData (rawData: RawData): ViewData {
  return {
    id: rawData.id,
    someOtherData: rawData.someOtherData,
    isVisible: Math.random() >= 0.5
  }
}
```

The example above works, but when dealing with really large objects it gets to be a bit of a maintenance headache especially when working with server data that can occasionally change. Rather than just updating one interface, I also need to update the map function(s).

In pure JavaScript I would write something like the function below. Given that I'm completely changing the implementation to fit with TypeScript I'm guessing there must be a better way. Is it possible to copy all the existing properties and add additional ones? What types would I add to the following?

```
function mapRawDataToViewData (rawData) {
  const viewData = copy(rawData) // Returns a copy so as not to mutate the original rawData
  viewData.isVisible = Math.random() >= 0.5
  return viewData
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten copying the properties using [Typescript's object spread syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#spread)

Eg:

```
function mapRawDataToViewData (rawData: RawData): ViewData {
  return {
    ...rawData,
    isVisible: Math.random() >= 0.5
  }
}
```

This way, all items of `RawData` are copied into the returned object and you need to copy only the additional properties of `ViewData`. And if you want to override one of the properties of the base (`RawData` in your case), you can do so **after** *spreading* the properties of the base, like so -

```
function mapRawDataToViewData (rawData: RawData): ViewData {
  return {
    ...rawData,
    someOtherData: "Overriden value",
    isVisible: Math.random() >= 0.5
  }
}
```